# Wordpress website title / line

Tags: html, wordpress

I am kinda new to the coding scene, so I really want to ask a question about the site name, in this case quite a long line which separates the name and the description of the site.

I'm trying to make something similar but I don't understand exactly how.

Attached a print.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MavUj.png)

I am using wordpress for my website.

thanks a lot guys,
F.

Comment: It's most likely in your templated header.php file. Something like `<?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?>`

Comment: thank you so much for this quick reply. I'll try that :)

Comment: If your question was about the "long line":
It is the `Em dash`: —
Press Alt + 0151
http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html

Comment: @DanielSixl thank you so much Daniel! I'll try my best but I still didn't find the ''<?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?>'' section on my website header.php.

Comment: do you using some `seo` plugin?

Comment: Well, how your wp-title is generated also depends on the theme you are using. Without looking at your files, it is hard to tell how it was implemented. But looking at your index.php you should be able to see what template parts are included. What theme are you using?
Samvel probably wants to point out, that with some of the SEO-Plugins you can configure your title settings, often even the separator symbol. 
Install i.e. Yoast SEO plugin and in it's settings enable advanced settings.  Then click on ‘Titles & Metas’. Search for ‘Title Separator’. Em-Dash is an option there, among others.